# use std::bind in lambda with std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2015, lambda

```
// By const l-value reference
auto func2 = std::bind([](const std::unique_ptr< std::vector<int> >& pw) // fine
{
    std::cout << "size of vector2: " << pw->size() << std::endl;
}, std::make_unique<std::vector<int>>(22, 1));

//By non-const l-value reference
auto func3 = std::bind([](std::unique_ptr< std::vector<int> >& pw) // fine
{
    std::cout << "size of vector3: " << pw->size() << std::endl;
}, std::make_unique<std::vector<int>>(22, 1));

// By Value
auto func4 = std::bind([](std::unique_ptr< std::vector<int> > pw) // error
{
    std::cout << "size of vector4: " << pw->size() << std::endl;
}, std::make_unique<std::vector<int>>(22, 1));
func4(); // without this line, compilation is fine. The VS generates error for the calling of the bind object.
// By r-value reference
auto func5 = std::bind([](std::unique_ptr< std::vector<int> >&& pw) // error
{
    std::cout << "size of vector5: " << pw->size() << std::endl;
}, std::make_unique<std::vector<int>>(22, 1));
func5(); // without this line, compilation is fine.
```

Why func4 and func5 fail to compile?

Comment: Your code compiles fine in VS2015. Please show error message at your side.

Comment: @Martin Zhai, if you add the line func4() or func5(), then you will see tons of errors.

Comment: Your primary problem is using `std::bind`.  As it happens you are also (predictably) getting other errors after making that first mistake.

Answer (score 4):

`func4` produces an error because the parameter of the lambda is passed by value. But `std::unique_ptr` is not copiable.

`func5` is more complex, we can read from documentation [std::bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind):

> Given an object g obtained from an earlier call to bind, when it is invoked in a function call expression `g(u1, u2, ... uM)`, an invocation of the stored object takes place, as if by `std::invoke(fd, std::forward<V1>(v1), std::forward<V2>(v2), ..., std::forward<VN>(vN))`, where `fd` is a value of type `std::decay_t<F>` the values and types of the bound arguments `v1`, `v2`, ..., `vN` are determined as specified below.
>   ...
>   the ordinary stored argument `arg` **is passed to the invokable object as lvalue argument**: the argument `vn` in the std::invoke call above is simply arg and the corresponding type `Vn` is `T cv &`, where *cv* is the same cv-qualification as that of `g`.

Therefore, even if `std::make_unique<std::vector<int>>(22, 1)` is a r-value,  a l-value is given to the lambda, which is not compatible with the r-value expected.
This can also explain why `func3` works fine.

Answer (score 2):

`bind` returns a function object that can be invoked more than once.

It takes its arguments and stores it in a tuple (or equivalent).  It then invokes the first argument with the rest.  This is similar to `std::invoke` from C++17.

For both of your failed cases, you could not call the lambda more than once.  So you get an error when you call it once, because *bind assumes you want to be able to call it again*.  Doing anything else would be madness, as it cannot know you are never calling it again in the context of its `operator()`.

Logically, those calls *should* fail.  The standard also mandates they fail, because the standard in this case behaves logically.

---

```
auto funcA =
  [pw=std::make_unique<std::vector<int>>(22,1)]
  {
    std::cout << "size of vector2: " << pw->size() << std::endl;
  };

auto funcB =
  [pw=std::make_unique<std::vector<int>>(22,1)]() mutable
  {
    std::cout << "size of vector2: " << pw->size() << std::endl;
  };
```

Here are two different lambdas that do roughly what your code did.  Instead of the bind and pass, we just capture.

In `funcA` we have a `const unique_ptr`, in `funcB` we have a non-`const` `unique_ptr`.  In the second, we could move out of the unique ptr; in the first, we cannot.

`std::bind` was written prior to lambdas existing in C++, and it is rarely a better idea than using a lambda.  The deficiencies in lambdas have mostly been removed by C++14, and there are very few situations where using `bind` instead of a lambda is a good idea.

`std::bind` generates cryptic error messages and has arcane behaviour in a number of corner cases, like passing the result of `bind` to another `bind`.